# coupled system of ODE with conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How to find the solution of the system of ODE of
\begin{aligned}
x'&= x-2y+\sin t \\
y'&=2x-y-\cos t 
\end{aligned}
with initial condition of $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$?

I found the general solution for both $x$ and $y$ already which is 
$$x(t)=C_1\cos(\sqrt{3}t) +C_2\sin(\sqrt{3}t)+ \frac{3}{2} \cos(t)+\frac{1}{2} \sin(t)$$ and
$$y(t)=C_1\cos(\sqrt{3}t) +C_2\sin(\sqrt{3}t)+\frac{1}{2} \cos(t)+\frac{3}{2} \sin(t)$$
But i don't understand how to satisfy the condition given? since there are 2 variables there which is $x$ and $t$. I know that $C_1$ and $C_2$ in both equation are equal.

Comment: is this $$C_1\cos(\sqrt{3}x)$$? etc

Comment: Please use mathjax to get help

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  For the homogeneous solutions? yes that's what i meant. Sorry i can't write it clearly

Comment: @Fakemistake I don't quite know how to use matlab to solve that question.  but then want i to know is how to solve it without matlab

Comment: @Fakemistake sorry i read it wrongly. oh i don't know what is mathjax. will try it!

Comment: Everything to the right of the equal signs is a function of $t$ and **not** $x$.

Comment: @Moo oh great thanks!

Comment: @Harry49 oh, so that is what it is for. Thanks for helping me edit it. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x(t)=C_1\cos(\sqrt{3}t) +C_2\sin(\sqrt{3}t)+3/2 \cos(t)+1/2 \sin(t)\qquad \text{is OK.}$$
But with $C_1$ and $C_2$ as coefficients in $x(t)$, the coefficients in $y(t)$ cannot be the same. So, $\quad y(t)=C_1\cos(\sqrt{3}t) +C_2\sin(\sqrt{3}t)+1/2 \cos(t)+3/2 \sin(t)\quad$ is not correct.

Since you don't type the intermediate calculus, one cannot say exactly where is the mistake.

I found :
$$y(t)=\frac{C_1-\sqrt{3}\:C_2}{2}\cos(\sqrt{3}t) +\frac{C_2+\sqrt{3}\:C_1}{2}\sin(\sqrt{3}t)+1/2 \cos(t)+3/2 \sin(t)$$

Then, with the initial conditions :
$$\begin{cases}
x(0)=C_1 +3/2 =0\\
y(0)=\frac{C_1-\sqrt{3}\:C_2}{2} +\frac{1}{2}=1
\end{cases}$$
you can find $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: I assumed OP had found the eigenvalues but neglected to find the corresponding eigenvectors

Comment: @Jjacquelin how do get the answer to the homogeneous solution to be like that? Because i still found cos (√3t) and sin(√3t) to be the answer

Comment: You found that $\cos(\sqrt{3}\:t)$ and $\sin(\sqrt{3}\:t)$ are particular solutions of the homogeneous ODE system. The general solution is $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, each one being a linear combination of them. What is the problem ?

Comment: @JJacquelin i meant that how do you get (C1−√3C2)/2 and (C2+√3C1)/2 ? Cause i seem to not get how you do this part

Comment: So, you have $$\begin{cases}x(t)=C_1\cos(\sqrt{3}\:t) +C_2\sin(\sqrt{3}\:t) \\y(t)=C_3\cos(\sqrt{3}\:t) +C_4\sin(\sqrt{3}\:t)\end{cases}$$ Put them into $\begin{cases}x'=x-2y\\y'=2x-y\end{cases}\quad$ Then solve for $C_3$ and $C_4$. This leads to $C_3=\frac{C_1-\sqrt{3}C_2}{2}$ and $C_4=\frac{C_2+\sqrt{3}C_1}{2}$

Comment: @JJacquelin oh! Thank you very much! it really help me